# Enterprise Tracking of Devices Logged into WiFi

Tags: wifi, user-tracking

If I have a Bring Your Own Device policy, how can I track whose device belongs to each IP address?  Do I need to collect information on all devices that use the WiFi system?

Answer (score 1):

Deploy 802.1x on the WiFi controllers or WPA2-Enterprise with a RADIUS server. This will allow you to track IP assignments to usernames. You could also record MAC addresses of these devices and map them to usernames in a spreadsheet. Depends what decade you want to be in.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  How do I know the usernames on my network?  That is, do I need to collect usernames beforehand for every device, or do devices automatically share obvious usernames?  We currently just have a group password that we share with anyone we wish to grant access.  As you can tell, I'm not an IT professional.

Comment: Achieving this goal may be a bit over your head then. Do you have any time of computer authorization like active directory or LDAP?

Comment: No, we don't; you just enter the password and then you have access.  It is over my head so I'm going to consult an IT buddy.

Comment: Yeah, that would be best. The poor mans way would be the spreadsheet method. Change the password. As people request it, write down their MAC address. You can then go into the router and find their IP, vice versa.